# Unable to make a copy of a doc even with the right ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that goes through a spreadsheet, retrieves values from the cells and inserts the values in a doc. The code works perfectly but I've noticed that when I make a copy of the doc, run the same code and pass the doc ID within the code I get the following error:

**No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it.**

I've tried to make the doc public but I get the same error. Interestingly if I create a new doc and pass that doc ID to the function it works just fine.

the code:

```
var templateid = "1IrEbukq3cVKg9MAPT-Aanfe4XCzoc-RCJKq6sOpQKGU"; // get template file id    
var copyDoc = DocsList.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(docName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood exactly when you problem occurs but I'd guess it is when you try to access copyDoc.
This is because you try to access it by its ID (as it appears from the error message) and you don't have it : from the code you write here copyDoc is a document, if you want its Id just add `.getId()` at the end like this :

```
var copyDoc = DocsList.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(docName).getId();
```

Hoping I had the right guess ;-)

You could also do that like this so you'll have everything ready to use :

```
  var doctemplate = DocumentApp.openById("1IrEbukq3cVKg9MAPT-Aanfe4XCzoc-RCJKq6sOpQKGU");// this can be placed outside the function as a global variable
  var docname="new name for the copy";
  var copydoc=DocsList.copy(doctemplate,docname);
  var copydocId = copydoc.getId();
```

Edit : corrected error in code following jwesonga comment (thx)

Comment: +serge-insas interestingly when I run Logger I can see the templateId just fine. Quick correction, there's no openById for DocList, there is one for DocumentApp.

Comment: Ooops, sorry and than you ;-)  Is it the template ID or the copyDoc ID that causes the error ?

Comment: +serge-insas interestingly when I run Logger I can see the templateId just fine. Quick correction, there's no openById for DocList, there is one for DocumentApp.

Just found that the problem I have arises when I share docs from my corp email to my personal email. Even when I make a copy of the original doc I still don't have permissions to manipulate the doc through the apps script.