# How can I modify a file that somebody else shares to me, like a spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working with Google script, I used:

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById('XXXXXXXXXX');
```

But when I run the script I get this error:

> "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have
>   permission to access it."

I checked what kind of permissions the spreadsheet's owner gives to  me, and I can edit it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the doc owned by a user in a domain? (Google Apps for Business, Education,etc.)? If so, admin controls may be blocking script access by policy.

Similar to [Unable to make a copy of a doc even with the right ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209531/unable-to-make-a-copy-of-a-doc-even-with-the-right-id).